# Get Parent ID based on Record Level - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran into P6 WBS where I need to import a schedule into a SQL Server table.

The structure of `WBS` in P6 like this:

[image: WBS P6 Structure]

When I Imported the table into SQL Server, I was able to identify each level using

```
CHARINDEX(LEFT(LTRIM(WBS), 1), WBS) -1 [Level]
```

Result:

[image]

My challenge was to retrieve `ParentID` based on the level where records lies (also based on its order) to get the below result:

[image]

How to get `ParentID` based on the level?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to get parentID from its level

Comment: Please do not post code / tables as image, post those as text instead.

Comment: You seem to be relying on the ordering of the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering of the rows, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Yes indeed, the order [ID] is the key of that, The Concept is to get ParentID based on the level given from its currnet ID.

Comment: Why should `1` and `2` have the same parent if they are on different levels? Why do the levels sometimes increase by two instead of one, that is why are there missing levels and what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a `CROSS APPLY`

**This is ASSUMING the IDs are sequential**

This will produce the desired results for this example, but there are risks as mentioned in the comments.

**Example**

```
Select A.* 
      ,B.ParentID 
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select max(ID) from YourTable Where Level<A.Level and ID<A.ID ) B(ParentID)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thats
 exactly what I need . Thanks alot.

Comment: @OmarShahineoshahine Always happy to help.

Comment: @OmarShahineoshahine Generally, when you find an answer which solves your problem, it is customary to ACCEPT it.